# IniFile.Create throws an exception EAccessViolation

Tags: delphi

This code seems to be in every example that I can find on the web ...

```
var IniFile: TIniFile;
    IniFileName : String;

IniFileName := ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, '.ini') ;
IniFile := IniFile.Create(IniFileName);
```

The `IniFile.Create` throws an exception `EAccessViolation`.

`IniFileName` is a full path, avoiding the trap of trying to write to the Windows directory. I can save a file to to it from a text editor, so there are no permission problems.

Any ideas what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: `IniFile := TIniFile.Create(IniFileName)` creates a new `TIniFile` object and saves its address in the local `IniFile` variable. Your `IniFile.Create` will call the `TIniFile.Create` method on the `IniFile` pointer, which, being a local variable of an unmanaged type, is a "random" pointer. Hence an AV (if you are lucky).

Comment: "This code seems to be in every example that I can find on the web ..." I doubt that very much, unless they're repeats of the same incorrect code

Comment: You just missed a single character ``T`` before the second ``IniFile`` in the last line!